# Golang binary keeps reference of source code names and paths

Tags: go

Out of curiosity, I've opened the binary generated by GO compiler using a HEX Editor and to my surprise, I found in the binary the full path and filename of every source code used in my project.

Like, it is clearly there information like **/home/myusername/myprojectname/source.go**

Even more surprised, I found things like comments of how specific function works

[image]

Now I know why a "Hello World" written in Golang and compiled generates a 3mb binary...

Does anyone know if there is a way to strip out these things from golang binaries? Like, any compiler flags?

Answer (score 5):

> I found things like comments of how specific function works

---

They are not comments. They are string literals, mostly error messages. For example,

```
malloc.go:  throw("persistentalloc: align is not a power of 2")

lfstack.go: print("runtime: lfstack.push invalid packing: node="
```

---

> Now I know why a "Hello World" written in Golang and compiled
>   generates a 3mb binary...

No, you don't.

> [Go: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [Why is my trivial program such a large binary?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_is_my_trivial_program_such_a_large_binary)
>
> The linker in the gc toolchain creates statically-linked binaries by
>   default. All Go binaries therefore include the Go runtime, along with
>   the run-time type information necessary to support dynamic type
>   checks, reflection, and even panic-time stack traces.
>
> A simple C "hello, world" program compiled and linked statically using
>   gcc on Linux is around 750 kB, including an implementation of printf.
>   An equivalent Go program using fmt.Printf weighs a couple of
>   megabytes, but that includes more powerful run-time support and type
>   and debugging information.
>
> A Go program compiled with gc can be linked with the -ldflags=-w flag
>   to disable DWARF generation, removing debugging information from the
>   binary but with no other loss of functionality. This can reduce the
>   binary size substantially.

---

> a "Hello World" written in Golang and compiled generates a 3mb
>   binary...

That is an exaggeration; it's 2.0MB.

```
$ go version
go version devel +c7026f9d14 Sat Feb 9 17:34:48 2019 +0000 linux/amd64
$ cat hello.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
$ go build hello.go
$ ./hello
Hello, 世界
$ ls -s -h ./hello
2.0M ./hello
$
```

Comment: @TTKDroid, I would add on my Linux/amd64 platform with GCC 6.3, a statically-built C program which performs a single `printf("Hello world\n");` compiles to the 792k binary (as measured by `ls -sh`). That's smaller than the Go version but note that the Go compiler links the whole Go _runtime_ in—the thing C simply does not have (channels, concurrency, reflection, and so on and so on).

Comment: @peterSO so you're saying that using  -ldflags=-w will remove the reference of my source code name from the binary? Today I have /home/<myuser>/<myproject>/file.go